# Find and Replace value using SED

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed

I have one file which contains key value pair

**properties.env**

```
development_port=8080
development_type=tcp
staging_port=8081
development_type=http
```

I need to read value from properties.env and replace it in another file based on some environment variable value lets say `ENVIRONMENT=staging/development`

**config.yml**

```
server:
  adminConnectors:
    -
      port: 18001
      type: http
```

The final output of **config.yml** should be if `ENVIRONMENT=staging`

```
server:
      adminConnectors:
        -
          port: 8081
          type: http
```

How can i achieve this using sed command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the properties file looks like it has the right syntax you could just source it, and then replace the entire port line:

```
source properties.env
sed --in-place "s/port.*/port: $staging_port/" config.yml
```

This, of course, assumes the "port" line appears only once in your config.

Comment: tried your command but it didnt replace the value. Final output  `port: $development_port`

Comment: @DarkCoder I goofed the sed syntax. Corrected now.

Comment: got it, it was because of missing single and double quote.   `sed -i '.backup' 's/port.*/port: '"$development_port"'/' config.yml`. Can you please edit your answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @DarkCoder I already edited the answer. Your version has way more quotes than is actually necessary.